# Como usar o método chunk do Laravel Excel?

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-excel, upload, import

```
public function uploadNotaCorte(Request $request, EstadoRepository $estadoRepository)
{
    $error      = array();
    $path       = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
    $notasCorte = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
    })->get();

    $chunk      = $notasCorte->chunk(100);

    foreach ($notasCorte as $key => $notaCorte) {
     //minhas regras
    }
    return  $error;
}
```

Estou tendo dificuldades para implementar o método `chunk` o codigo acima funciona normalmente em arquivos pequenos mais em arquivos maiores da `error` por causa do tamanho.

Preciso fazer um upload de um arquivo com ***120.000*** registros e tentando usar o `chunk` para isso, não sei o que posso esta fazendo errado e olhei a documentação mais e bem simples e não consegui resolver o problema alguém pode me ajudar?

[Documentação Laravel Excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#chunk)

Comment: Qual é a exceção que é gerada?

Comment: Boa noite Vigílio  o problema e a memoria o processamento e muito grande  devido ao chunk() na esta funcionando dai o servidor cai, só estou querendo passa esse metodo chunk() para não gerar um processamento muito grande  e funcionar corretamente.